# GeoLocationService Multiple bindings in Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, geolocation

Edited the question to simply further... If I use the following code in any controller (using Chrome), I get the output as expected, but it ends up printing "Something" 4 times. What am I missing?

```
  $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        console.log("Something");
        console.log(position);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you using $rootScope.$apply in your service??

Comment: I have edited the question since I was able to isolate it further.

Comment: it would be helpful if you create a fiddle.